# Android Exception in FingerprintService

Tags: android, dalvik, android-fingerprint-api

**dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace VMStack.java, line -2**
android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace: at com.android.server.fingerprint.FingerprintService.isForegroundActivity(FingerprintService.java:1243) at com.android.server.fingerprint.FingerprintService.canUseFingerprint(FingerprintService.java:1310) at com.android.server.fingerprint.FingerprintService.canUseFingerprint(FingerprintService.java:1265) at com.android.server.fingerprint.FingerprintService.access$2500(FingerprintService.java:149) at com.android.server.fingerprint.FingerprintService$FingerprintServiceWrapper.authenticate(FingerprintService.java:2052)